# Can I convert big XLSX file to XLSB for better performance?

Tags: microsoft-excel

We are working with big excel (xlsx) files, around 50mb-200mb.

Can we open the files and save them as xlsb format? to get better performance and smaller size.
or do we need to build excel files from scratch?

Generally should we always use xlsb when building big excel files?

Thanks

Comment: Is this your real question? As you should have been able to see when you go to the `Save As` dialog, you can save an Excel file in many different formats.  And the only difference I'd expect to see xlsx vs xlsb would be a difference in loading time.

Comment: I can save it but will all the formulas/links/macro and stuff be transferred to new format as it is? the structure I mean.

Comment: Yes, in memory the files are the same. The only difference is how they are stored on the disc.

Comment: Refer to this articel: https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-save-as-binary-excel-workbook.html

Answer (score 1):

I use xlsb for every file I create in excel, they are small and allow macros to run, I have not found any drawbacks for using this file type.

And yes you can save a file as another file type by going to saves as and choosing the file type.

This Microsoft support page should give you all the basics in getting started with saving files in Excel. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-your-workbook-92e4aae0-452d-497f-a470-570610ff720a